# How to attach webView with another activity so that it opens the webPage related to different posts in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, webview

I am using `webView` in my application and have another activity with different posts, I want to attach my `webView` to those posts so that if I click on post 1 the webPage which is **linked** to it opens up and if I click on post 2 the webPage linked to that post opens up in same `webView`, is there any way to do so. Also I am using `firebase` as a database and fetching my web URL from the database. Please help.

I am using Android Studio

**webView class file:**

```
public class webViewNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webviewthis;
    private DatabaseReference mdataRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("webing");
        webviewthis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mdataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                post2web webView = dataSnapshot.getValue(post2web.class);
                webviewthis.loadUrl(webView.getWebViewPost());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: try something like this pass url using intent to your webview activity than display that url in webview

Comment: @NileshRathod  for that i have to assign multiple intents for all the posts. but i want only one intent which when triggers open webView and in that webView different web pages can be shown according to posts in my application

Comment: than create one method for that when you need start webviewe just call this method of intent

Comment: @NileshRathod yes that can be done i guess but can you show me any example of it or link so that it would be more clear, i am new to android and still learning sir.

Comment: check my below ans

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the url of that post and pass it with `intent` to webview activity.
Instead of using activity for webview, it is better to open webview in fragment.
It would be faster and easier

Comment: by passing it with intent, i have to place multiple intents in my program for every post i add. and sir can you show me some link or code to use webview with fragment

Comment: can you explain how it will **better to open webview in fragment. It would be faster and easier**

Answer (score 0):

try this create one method like this

```
public static void callWebview(Context context, String url) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, webViewNews.class);
        i.putExtra("url", url);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

when you need to start webview activity than just call this methos like this

```
callWebview(this,"https://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: can i get url from firebase database with this method?

Comment: first get url from firebase than call this method

Comment: did not get it sir!! please tell more

Comment: where would i create this method, in my webviewNews activity or in my post  activity

Comment: you can crate this method any where because its a static method you can add this methos in your post activity

Comment: and what should i add on the place of the stackoverflow.com URL because i have to get it from firebase.

Comment: but sir i am unable to get firebase url, actually i have implemented a button on which when we click opens the webView, and now with your method i am placing `callwebView();` inside the onClick but it is not letting me grab my url from firebase.